# jQuery tabs in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a desktop version of my website and a mobile version. The mobile version is using bootstrap for its responsiveness. In the forums I have a bbcode that is using jquery's tabs widget so the html structure is like this:

```
<div class="tabs_wrap">
<ul class="forum_tabs">
<li><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabspane">
content for tab1
</div>
<div class="tabspane">
content for tab2
</div>
```

But in Bootstrap this doesn't work because the tabs are using different css classes and the panels are wrapped in another div. Is there a way I could make it work without changing the html?

Comment: bbcode? where??

Comment: I read, and re-read, and then read again, and I still have no idea what you're trying to do, could you add a jsfiddle example please

Answer (score 0):

You know there're rules to using bootstrap tab, your code is not using any of them.

Try this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs forum_tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane tabspane active">
    content for tab1
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane tabspane">
    content for tab2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I mean. The jquery tabs work with just adding "$("ul.forum_tabs").tabs("> .tabspane");" but the bootstrap requires additional classes like nav-tabs, etc and data-toggle attributes. Why does it not work like this?